Laravel - Route in app.php is missing, but web.php works
I'm new to laravel.  I've created a project as document said, then in my web.php, I have
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\StockController;

Route::get('/stocks',[StockController::class,'index']);

so when I fetch http://127.0.0.1:8000/stocks it works and show me a json data.
While in api.php, I have the exactly same code, I know it has a prefix of /api so I fetch http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stocks
But it keep returning a 404 Not Found html page for me.
What I have tried but not work so far:

Clean cache using php artisan route:cache & php artisan route:clear.
Restart my php app
Comment out web.php

Anyone mind to help?

start with php artisan route:list to see if you have the route working

Can you please specify laravel version. As there were some major changes in laravel 11 for API. If it is 11, attach part of bootstrap/app.php.

@ZaidMalek this is it, I'm using laravel ^11.31, and it seems like I have to add a line in withRouting function in order to get my api.php working, thanks for the help!
This is what I've done for people looking at this answer in the future.
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(DIR))
->withRouting(
web: DIR.'/../routes/web.php',
api: DIR.'/../routes/api.php',
commands: DIR.'/../routes/console.php',
health: '/up',
)

Actually I want to post my solution here, thanks for the help from ZaidMalek.
As for the official documentation on Routing, it seems that we need to add the route of api.php in bootstrap/app.php.  So the code in app.php would be:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php', 
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

